# How to output uploading errors as flashdata - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I'm wanting to display any errors produced while uploading a file by redirecting the user back to the same page they used to upload the file. The thing is that I pre-populate some inputs on that page, so I can't use `redirect(controller/method_to_load_page)` as that wouldn't carry out the data population.

Using `$this->load->view('add_page',$error);` won't work either (the way that I'm using it), because although that will show the errors, it won't show the input fields with the pre-populated data.

This is the method in my controller which loads the form to upload a file and other fields:

```
public function add_products_page()
    {
        //get each categories subcategory and place them in their own variable
        $data['categories1'] = $this->admin_model->getSubcategories('1');
        $data['error'] = '';
        $this->load->view('add_page',$data);
    }
```

And from that page, the user can fill in the form and choose an image. The form will then be submitted to this method in the same controller:

```
public function add_book()
    {
        $id = $this->admin_model->add_book();

        $config['file_name'] = $id;
        $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('add_page', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('admin/add_products_page', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

If there are no errors, the redirect to add_products_page() method is okay, however when there's an error, the view 'add_page' is loaded and the errors are shown, but my pre-populated field isn't populated anymore because the method to do that isn't being called.

So I really would like to know how I can both load my view by calling the method add_products_page to populate my input fields, and also show errors when they occur. Please if someone could help I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Answer I used is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934712/how-to-passing-validation-error-data-through-redirect

Answer (score 0):

Why post to a different method and then redirect? You can handle it all in the same method.

```
public function add_products_page()
{
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
    {
        $result = $this->_add_book();
        if ($result['is_error'])
        {
            // TODO: whatever it takes to show an error message
            $data['error'] = $result['message'];
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: whatever it takes to show a success message
            $data['error'] = '';
        }
    }

    //get each categories subcategory and place them in their own variable
    $data['categories1'] = $this->admin_model->getSubcategories('1');
    $this->load->view('add_page',$data);
}

public function _add_book() // add underscore so it's not directly accessible
{
    $result = array(
        'is_error' => TRUE,
        'message' => '',
    );

    $id = $this->admin_model->add_book();

    $config['file_name'] = $id;
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        // set an error message
        $result['message'] = $error;
    }
    else
    {
        // set a success message
        $result['is_error'] = FALSE;
        $result['message'] = 'SOME SUCCESS MSG';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The method 'add_products_page' is kind of like a blank form, it's not just handling adding of books but other types of products as well, so that's why its kinda separated. I just found an answer which works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934712/how-to-passing-validation-error-data-through-redirect. Thank you for the reply though, I'll look into improving my code